# how to Display data get from JSON in View controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

I have idea how to display data in `UITableViewController` in cell by index.row but i don't have idea how to show data in viewController

for e.g.

when i use `UITableViewController` that time,

> NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[self.data
>   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] valueForKey:@"profile_image"]]; // data
>   is my array

this code will get image from array and set it in particular cell with the help of index.row.

but when i am using `UIViewController` then how i should set data for particular view??

Please provide me your guidance for this issue that how can i set image form array to my ViewController as i set it in `UITableViewController` by `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row` .

Thanks

Comment: U want to set image from array to view controller background. Is that so?

Comment: u want selected cell image will show on other view controller?

Comment: What exactly have you tried, and what do you specifically want to do? Do you want to show the image in a different screen (`UIViewController`) for a specific profile? Are you passing the proper data to that view controller (e.g. `[self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` when a cell is selected)?

Comment: What's stopping you from running a search?  There has been nothing new with the subject you propose.

Comment: Why do you use `NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"` and `valueForKey:`?

Comment: Do you want to know how to pass data to a UIViewController? Create a property in .h and assign It in your VC instance, for example...

Comment: You can use tag for each view like 0,1,2,3 and so on,,,, and instead of suing indexpath.row  you can use the tag  NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[self.data objectAtIndex:yourview.tag ] valueForKey:@"profile_image"]]; // data is my array

Comment: @palak Please provide some more code so that we can understand your problem where you stuck

Comment: Thanks to all for give your guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i asked the above question but i got answer myself after many research and defiantly with the help of my stackoverflow's intelligent friends.

so i like to post my answer.

my answer is if i take `int` value `i`  and then i use it in my function then it look like below code..

```
  [requestDynamic startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

       // Insert your code here

        NSLog(@"%@",result);
        self.arrData = nil;
        self.arrData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.arrData = [result[@"data"] mutableCopy];


        int i =0;
//        NSString *strImage1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.arrData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"picture"]];
        NSString *strComment =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[self.arrData objectAtIndex:i ]valueForKey:@"message"]];
        NSString *strLike = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[[self.arrData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"likes"]valueForKey:@"summary"]valueForKey:@"total_count"]];
        NSString *strCommentCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[[self.arrData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"comments"]valueForKey:@"summary"]valueForKey:@"total_count"]];


        CustomSocialView *imageView1 = [[CustomSocialView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
        [imageView1 setContentText:strComment like:strLike comment:strCommentCount];
```

may be this question and answer is silly for you all experienced people but it is very important for me and some others like me.

so i post answer as i got it.

Thank you